# React 3D surface charts

Tags: javascript, reactjs, user-interface, 3d

I am working on a web application, where one of the use cases is to build a chart/graph that represents the temperature in a building as shown in the image.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uQOBw.png)

I have used plotly using java script, our UI is being written using react. Can someone give me a brief idea how i can do it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.